# Create a form button with no action

Tags: javascript, forms, button, submit

I have this button in a simple form:

```
<input type="image" src="/img/search_ws.png" onClick="if (emptySearchField == true) doNothing()" id="search_btn" />
```

If the condition (`emptySearchField == true`) The button should do nothing, else we submit the form

How would I manage to do that ?

Comment: And what does it does if not true ? Should it submit the form ? In that case you're probably interested in the form onsubmit event handler.

Comment: @dystroy Yes, The form is submited if not true, but Im more intrested in not submiting the form by clicking on the submit button

Answer (score 1):

I think return false would do it

```
onClick="if (emptySearchField == true) return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" src="/img/search_ws.png" onClick="if (emptySearchField == true) return false;" id="search_btn" />
```